# Cómo convertir un string codificado en Base64 a Imagen para mostrarla sobre un PanelSD?

Tags: genexus

Tenemos una API Rest llamada jderest/file/list la cual llamamos desde un Procedure desarrollado en Genexus ubicado dentro de uno de los eventos de un PanelSD.
Esta API al hacer post:

```
&httpclient.AddHeader('Content-type','application/json')
&httpclient.Execute('POST','/jderest/file/list?')
&SDTAttach_OUT.FromJson(&httpclient.ToString())
```

… nos devuelve una lista de archivos adjuntos en formato JSON que luego convertimos a una variable del tipo SDT.

Si se trata de una imagen adjunta, dentro del JSON en  "data" contiene una string codificado en Base64 de la imagen.

Cómo se podría hacer desde Genexus para convertir un string codificado en Base64 a Imagen para mostrarla sobre el panel ?

También dentro del JSON de salida tenemos la ubicación dentro de "file" pero por temas de Seguridad Informática no podemos permitir que desde una app online accedan desde afuera accedan directo al servidor

```
{
    "mediaObjects": [
        {
            "data": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACgAAAAoCAYAAACM/rhtAAAImklEQVR42sVYaWxjVxUe........RCV2AQgc1QmCC",
            "file": "\\\\Servidor\\E920\\MEDIAOBJ\\HTMLUpload\\FILE-192-168-1-181-3867018675022611-1681390717719.png",
            "itemName": "MicrosoftTeams-image (5).png",
            "link": "\\\\Servidor\\E920\\MEDIAOBJ\\HTMLUpload\\FILE-192-168-1-181-3867018675022611-1681390717719.png",
            "moType": 5,
            "queue": "",
            "sequence": 1,
            "updateDate": "2023-04-13",
            "updateHourOfDay": 9,
            "updateMinuteOfHour": 58,
            "updateSecondOfMinute": 56,
            "updateTimeStamp": 95856,
            "updateUserID": "JPEREZ",
            "hasValidTimestamp": true,
            "isDefaultImage": false,
            "isImage": false,
            "isMisc": false,
            "isOLE": false,
            "isShortCut": false,
            "isText": false,
            "isUpdated": false,
            "isURL": true
        }
    ]
}
```